# Sort string without any builtin methods

Tags: javascript, string, sorting, replace, functional-programming

I want to sort a string in javascript without using a built in method, just by using for's and comparisons like 'a' > 'b';

Something that doesn't work:

```js
function replaceAt(str, i, char) {
    return str.substr(0,i) + char + str.substr(i + 1)
}

function swap(str, i1, i2) {
    return replaceAt(replaceAt(str, i1, str[i2]),i2,str[i1]);
}

function sort(str) {
    var sorted = str;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (str[i] > str[i + 1]) {
            str = swap(str, i, i+1)
        }
    }
    return str;
}
```

Pseudo-code or books, courses recommendations on programming are welcome!

Comment: Sort string how exactly? Give us an example of what a sorted string would look like.

Comment: You're only swapping adjacent elements. I suggest you read up on proper sorting algorithms. Any serious programmer should have a copy of Knuth's "Sorting and Searching" on their bookshelf.

Comment: So, `str = str.split('').sort().join('');` is not what you want? :-P

Comment: @Barmar: Thank you barmar, but I'm also looking for a book on algorithms and programming in general, the irony is that I can freelance and built complete web apps being a bad programmer so I just imagine what I could do If I was a good one.
RocketHazmat: thank u, but nope!

Comment: **Step 1:** Pick a sort algorithm from the many, many that exist.  **Step 2:** Implement that sort algorithm.  Do not proceed to step 2, until you have finished step 1.  Since you appear to be doing this as a learning exercise, it is worth taking some time to understand several different sort algorithms and what their relative strengths are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is not applying any sort algorithm logic, I recommend you to read atleast 1 to solve your problem.

Below is the program, which produces the expected output from your program using [selection sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).

`swap` and `replace` functions works fine.

```
function sort(str) {
    var sorted = str;
    //Selection sort
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        for(var j = i + 1; j < str.length - 1; j++) {   
            if (str[i] < str[j]) {
                str = swap(str, i, j)
            }
        }
    }
    return str;
}

console.log(sort("zaasfweqrouoicxzvjlmmknkniqwerpopzxcvdfaa"));
//output: aaaaccdeeffiijkklmmnnoooppqqrrsuvvwwxxzzz
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function sort(arr) {
    arr = arr.split("");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[i]) {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr.join("");
}
console.log(sort("dcna"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sort(arr) {
    arr = arr.split("");
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[i]) {
                [arr[j], arr[j+1]] = [arr[j+1], arr[j]]
            }
        }
    }
    return arr.join("");
}
console.log(sort("dcna"));

Note: no need of using temp variable
```

Comment: Can you explain your code give the OP a recipe/pattern for solving similar tasks? E.g. where is the conditional swap done? What is the `if` comparing?  Why `split` and `join` needed?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
array=[4, 10, 2, 9, 6, 3, 13, 5];
function arrayOperations()
{
    var count = array.length - 1,
        temp,
        j,
        i;

    for (j = 0; j < count; j++)
    {

        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            if (array[i] > array[i + 1])
            {
                temp = array[i + 1];
                array[i + 1] = array[i];
                array[i] = temp;
            }

        }
    }
document.write("ascending order is <br>")
for(k=0;k<=array.length-1;k++){
    document.write(array[k]+ "<br>");
    }

document.write("descending order is <br>")
for(k=array.length-1;k>=0;k--){

        document.write(array[k]+ "<br>");
    }
document.write("biggest number is <br>")
for(k=array.length-1;k>=0;k--){

        if((array[k])>array[k-1]){
        document.write(array[k]+"<br>")
        break;
        }
    }
document.write("smallest number is <br>")
for(k=0;k<=array.length;k++){

        if((array[k])<array[k+1]){
        document.write(array[k]+"<br>")
        break;
        }
    }




    }




</script>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
array=[4, 10, 2, 9, 6, 3, 13, 5]
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="arrayOperations()" value="find">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//generic sort function to sort a word
function sortArray(str){
let strr = str.split('');
for(var index = 0 ;index <strr.length ;index ++ ){
    for(var index1 = 0;index1<(strr.length-index) ;index1++){
      let temp;
      if( strr[index1] > strr[index1+1] ){
            temp = strr[index1] ;
          strr[index1] = strr[index1 +1];
         strr[index1+1] =temp;
        }
     }
 }
  return(strr.join(''));
}

//data set to sort
let data = "Hey Goodmorning How are you";
let result;
let data1 =data.split(' ');
data1.forEach(value => {
  value = sortArray(value.toLowerCase());
  if(result){
  result += " ";
  result += value;
  }
  else {result = value;}
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.